# VS publishing to Azure causes runtime error

Tags: .net, azure, deployment, publish

When we publish our .NET project to Azure websites, during the actual publish, the live site gets runtime errors, or just times out for a minute or two.

We often need to publish changes to the site during the day, and can't afford this to happen.

Is this normal? Is there a better way to publish / deploy?

Comment: Can you post one of the errors ?

Comment: I can't remember the exact message, but it's one of those yellow .NET errors with a runtime error message. It's because some of the project .dll's are busy being uploaded when the request happens. I know one can simply put up an app_offline.htm while publishing, but that's not ideal for our high volume site to see everything go off - imagine people in the middle of a transaction etc.

Comment: What level of hosting are you using for the website (Free, Shared or Reserved)?  During the publish operation, you'd expect the website to become temporarily unavailable.  However, if you are using Shared or Reserved, you'll be able to run additional instances of the website.  In these cases, when you publish the site will remain available.

Comment: Other way is move up to cloud services and then swap out from staging to live. Works really well if you are pushing releases out to high volume sites in general.

Comment: no need to run additional instance to deploy to temporarily or move to cloud services to use staging slots... Azure Websites now supports staging slots.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. We're using a reserved instance, but would rather not have to set up a separate instance, and we'd like to stay away from cloud services (for now) for various reasons. We were just curious what the community does in general - for example, how come one never sees S.O. go down when they're publishing?

I think we will take a chance with the Azure Websites staged publishing, even though it's only in preview mode.

One other thing we're wondering is what about updates that involve a DB update? How do you stage that?